# Панель управления SAmp

Tags: phpmyadmin, php

SQL-запрос:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
Username varchar( 40 ) PRIMARY KEY ,
PASSWORD varchar( 32 ) 
)
```

Ответ MySQL:

> `#1050 - Table 'Users' already exists`

Comment: За констатацию факта спасибо, а вопрос в чем?

Answer (score 1):

Mysql Ответил тебе, что такая таблица уже существует.Правильнее формировать запрос в таком стиле,где проверяется создана уже таблица или нет  
     CREATE TABLE Users IF NOT EXISTS Users(
    Username varchar( 40 ) PRIMARY KEY ,
    PASSWORD varchar( 32 ) 
   )